# In Blender 2.8 can I render an image in SVG format?

Tags: rendering, file-format, svg

I need to render an image in SVG format and I don't see the option any where but I know you can do this in 2.79 using freestyle or addons. How do you do this in 2.8?

Comment: SVG is a vector format and Blender creates bitmap images. They're very different, so I would think not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Freestyle in Blender 2.8 just like in 2.79. The svg export for freestyle has to be activated in the preferences (*Edit > Preferences > Add-ons*).

[image]